# Не работает вызов процедуры из MySql

Tags: php

Первая причина, по которой может показаться, что я налажал с соединением к БД, хотя это не так. Я ранее использовал тот же самый объект для вызова процедуры из MYSQL, вызов произошёл успешно.

```
$procedure = new Procedure();
$accounts = $procedure->displayAccounts();// мои аккаунты, созданные в БД, возвращаются в виде массива успешно и отображаются в виде таблицы
$q = $procedure->displayQuestions(1);//здесь я пробую отобразить вопросы по категории, код данного метода приведен ниже
var_dump($q);
```

Весь класс Procedure:

```
<?php


class Procedure
{
    public $user;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = new User();
    }

    public function displayQuestions($catId){
        $query = $this->user->connection->query("Call `questionsCategory`('$catId')");
        $h=array();
        if($query->num_rows>0){
            while($row = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                $h[]=$row;
            }
            return $h;
        }
        else{
            return $h;
        }
    }
    public function displayAccounts(){
        $query = $this->user->connection->query("Call displayAccounts ");
        $php = [];
        if($query->num_rows>0){
            while($row = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                $php[]=$row;
            }
            return $php;
        }
        else{
            return $php;
        }
    }
}
```

Запрос при вызове в MySQL успешно срабатывает, но вот при использовании PHP результат выбивает в виде пустого массива данных
[image: Empty table]

Процедура, создаваемая в MYSQL, которую хочу использовать в коде, настройки процедуры:
[image: Procedure MySQL]

Интерпретатором PHP никаких ошибок не выдаёт, но вызов процедуры почему-то не срабатывает.

Comment: Как создавали процедуру?

Comment: Database - Routines - Add Routine

Comment: Решено, дело в объекте, для которого использовал первую процедуру. Я создал новый объект и чудесным образом заработало.

Comment: Для меня остаётся загадкой: почему первый объект не выдерживал вызова второй процедуры?